# use SUM with left join get me wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

So I have :

```
CREATE TABLE A (id INT,type int,amount int);
INSERT INTO A (id,type,amount) VALUES (1,0,25);
INSERT INTO A (id,type,amount) VALUES (2,0,25);
INSERT INTO A (id,type,amount) VALUES (3,1,10);


CREATE TABLE B (id INT,A_ID int,txt text);
INSERT INTO B (id,A_id,txt) VALUES (1,1,'abc');
INSERT INTO B (id,A_id,txt) VALUES (2,1,'def');
INSERT INTO B (id,A_id,txt) VALUES (3,2,'xxx');
```

I run this query:

```
SELECT min(A.id), SUM(A.amount), COUNT(B.id) FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id
GROUP BY A.type
```

I get :

```
min(A.id)   SUM(A.amount)   COUNT(B.id)
1           75              3
3           10              0
```

But I'm instead expecting to get :

```
min(A.id)   SUM(A.amount)   COUNT(B.id)
1           50              3
3           10              0
```

Can someone help? What is the best way to achieve this exact result ? 
I want group BY type and get SUM of grouped A.amount and get count() of all B corresponding to its foreign key.

here is the repro : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/esu13uGLcgFDpX7aEQRMJR/0 please RUN sql code.

EDIT to add more detail : I know **the result is correct** if I remove group by we can see 
1, 50, 2
2, 25, 1

But I expect the above result, what is the best way to achieve it ? I want make SUM of a TYPE then count all B related to this groupped A

Comment: Please tag only the DBMS you are using.

Comment: When you do your join you have two rows in tableb that have a type of 1. So you get all the rows in tablea with type a for EACH row in tableb. Take away the aggregation and you will see the rows being returned.

Comment: Run the query without any aggregation... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sAqaUyG1E9rHyqsXkoF2pz/0 See. Now it's obvious why you get that result

Comment: `SUM` doesn't sum the distinct rows, it sums all the rows in that group. Try `SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id WHERE a.type = 0;` and you'll see you get 3 rows with the value `25` for `amount`, and `3 * 25 = 75` not `50`.

Comment: thank you @larnu im aware of that what is the way to achieve this

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.  Which one is this???

Comment: its about sql-server (mysql was removed updated), what is the way to get 50 and 3 or it is not possible ?

Comment: The result you obtain is correct you have 2 time A_ID = 1 and one for A_ID = 2  .. 2x25  +25

Comment: In SQL Server this is trivial to work around.  In MySQL 5.7 you are out of luck I'm afraid.  I mean you "could" probably do it, but it's going to be painful at best.

Comment: @all yes the result is correct my question is : how can I get my expected result please ?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you SUM from an 1-N relation.

The matching records can multiply the result.

For example, when 1 records in A are joined with 2 in B it returns 2 times the amount of A before the GROUP BY.  So a SUM then doubles A.amount.

A way to get around that is using sub-queries that join one-on-one.

And a COUNT DISTINCT can be used to count unique id's.
So this just a way to get the SUM of A correct.

```
SELECT 
 q1.type, 
 q1.min_id, 
 q2.amount, 
 COALESCE(q1.totalB, 0) as totalB
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
    A.type,
    MIN(A.id) AS min_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) AS totalB
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.id
    GROUP BY A.type
 ) AS q1
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
   type,
   SUM(amount) AS amount 
  FROM A 
  GROUP BY type
) AS q2 ON q2.type = q1.type
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/SDmJJWYt5bXfJ4M3fp3Yk/1)

The SQL is tested for MySql. But it's an ANSI standard SQL that would run on almost any RDBMS, including MS Sql Server.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shorter version of the solution. It counts B_IDs first in the inner query, so I need to Sum the counts in the outer query.

```
SELECT  min(A.id), SUM(A.amount), Sum(Bid) FROM A
LEFT JOIN (select count(id) as Bid, A_id from B group by A_id) as Bcount  
ON A.id = Bcount.A_id
GROUP BY A.type
```

Comment: Aggregate related table based on foreign_key so each row became unique. Now join with main table and aggregate required columns of main and related table.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT A.id AS Aid,
            A.[type],
            A.amount,
            B.id AS bid,
            txt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY B.id) AS RN
     FROM A
          LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_ID)
SELECT MIN(Aid) AS Min_A_ID,
       SUM(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN amount END) AS Amount,
       COUNT(bid) AS BCount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [type];
```

I also recommend getting rid of that `text` datatype and using `varchar(MAX)`.